# Stop Crosstab summary display string count from Resetting on each page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a crosstab in Crystal Reports XI with a display string that displays a count for each time the condition is met:

Basically I have a summary column amountspent that I need to compare to avblcredit, and count every order where amountspent (the summary) exceeds avblcredit for each group, customer. I then have to display the total amount of orders for that customer where available credit is exceeded.

After much struggle due to the fact that I cannot use calculated members in Crystal Xi. I
created a second duplicate summary for item exditures and edited the display string of the second summary to compare itself to avbl credit then count:

```
global numbervar count;
 if currentvalue > avblcredit
    then count := count + 1; 
count;
```

The count then increments everywhere it finds the current value (sum of items) > available credit.

This works correctly if the crosstab prints fully on the page, however if the crosstab extends to the next page the count resets back to 0.

So basically as an example page 1 looks as follows:

```
customer 1
orders avblcredit amountspent count itema itemb itemc
ord1    4000         6000        1   2000  3000  1000
ord2    3734         5001        2   1000  2000  2001
ord3    4123         5000        3   4000  1000  0
ord4    2321         5000        4   5000  0     0
ord5    4000         5003        5   1200  3800  3
ord6    4000         6000        6   1000  2000  3000
```

page 2 with customer 1 group continued:

```
orders avblcredit amountspent count itema itemb itemc
ord7    4000         6000        1   2000  3000  1000
ord8    3734         5001        2   1000  2000  2001
ord9    4123         5000        3   4000  1000  0
ord10   2321         5000        4   5000  0     0
```

My question is how can I get my count from resetting on each new page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your datasource, you can do the calculation upstream.  Just extend your existing dataset with a new field named something like **spentExceedsCredit** with a value of 0 or 1.  Then you can sum them per customer, or use custom formatting in the report, or have the list of customer expenditures exceed a page, or whatever, and you're not dependent on Crystal's global variables.